# Issue using Exposed filters along with contextual filters in views

Tags: 7, views

I have a view page listing my stories/articles. I have a contextual filter based on the field Country which is a taxonomy term reference field. I have defined the path of the page as article-search/% to accommodate the contextual filter value.

I have an exposed filter on the field article-category which is also of type taxonomy term reference. I use better exposed filters to display the exposed filter values as links.

The contextual filter works fine and I configured the url to display taxonomy name instead of term id. This part works fine but when I click on any of the links in the exposed filter the taxonomy term name for the contextual filter value changes to %25 instead of the taxonomy name and the contextual filter fails. It works fine if I use the default dropdown option for the exposed filter instead of better exposed forms.

Any idea if there is an issue with better exposed filters when used along with contextual filters?

Comment: Sounds like it, have you checked the issue queue?

Comment: Have you added any `hook_form_alter` for expose filter?

Comment: It is an issue with BEF module and provided the solution in my answer below. Thanks Darvanen and Sumit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry! I should have looked at the issue queue. There is already an issue logged for this. Here is the link to the issue https://www.drupal.org/node/2179169

The issue got resolved when I applied the patch provided by Jim Keller in the issue link 
https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/better_exposed_filters-fix_exposed_block_link_path-2179169-1.patch